# Creating a virtual host

Tags: kali-linux, hosts, virtual-host

I'm using Kali Linux (backtrack Linux) and it already comes with apache, mysql, php (and plenty of other useful languages). I know that of course as with anything, you can programmatically build a system for VH's from scratch but I'm not that proficient. I was wondering if there was already something built into my OS that I could use to set up a VH for the sake of getting better with web development without having to use an online domain. I know in Windows, if you browse the system files and go to the etc or conf folder, there's a file called hosts that you can modify to setup a local host, thus allowing you to build mock websites on your local machine. Does Linux have an equivalent built into the OS? I'm not looking for third party or additional software, I'd just like to work with what I've got. Kali Linux is debian.

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/hosts` file is the equivalent that you're looking for in Linux.

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, that's exactly what I needed